# Handling TextView in UI thread from another thread does NOT throw an exception

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm making proof of concept example and I tried the code below. I should see an exception of handling UI element inside different Thread but the code works with no problems !:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                tv1.setText("I'm inside differnt thread");
            }
        }).start();

    // This also works !    
//  TestingThread t = new TestingThread();
//  t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    class TestingThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();

            //simulate download
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

            }

            tv1.setText("I'm inside differnt thread");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorta found the problem.

The thread is taking very small amount of time and it's inside the `onCreate()` method. It finishes before even the UI appears on the screen. If I moved this code to `onResume()` (after UI becomes visible) or make it takes long time by some sleep() calls, it crashes as expected.